# Automatic change of linked server name for a newly restored database

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are requesting backup/restore from PROD to TEST environment. Is there a way to update the linked server name of Stored Procedures pointing to Test server.
For example: 
one stored procedure(prod) used a linked server like [prodservername].[database].[table]
once this stored procedure restored in test then i need to edit the linked server used in stored procedure to [testservername].[database].[table].
The thing is we have a lot of SP that used linked server in calling some data and we don't want to do that manually. Is there a way to automate this process? Please help thanks!

```
SELECT 
   column1,
   column2,
   column3
FROM
   [ProductionServerName].[Database].dbo.[Table] --Need to change [ProductionServerName] to [TestServerName] 
WHERE column1 = 'Sample'
```

Comment: Instead of changing names in SP, why not change the linked server definition to point to your TEST server?

Comment: If you are going to change the linked definition then it will point to production server. Have you ever tried the approach you are suggesting?

Comment: In the above example SP where it points to [ProductionServerName], then if you change the linked server definition then it seems that you are actually pointing it to prod right? Because we don't what to edit linked server names n SP. @Ivien kindly elaborate your suggestion. thanks

Comment: the `PROD` and `TEST` is it on the same `SQL Server` ?

Comment: separate server thats why we used linked server...

Comment: Then why not use a generic name for the `Linked Server` and in the definition point to different server for `PROD` and `TEST` ?

Comment: Thanks @Squirrel. That would be nice if the implementation used a generic linked server name, but we are currently working at a legacy sql server and it takes much effort to deal with the existing linked servers whenever we request for backup/restore of data. Is there any other way?

Comment: to update the linked server name in stored procedure, you will need to scan through all SP, perform string parsing and replace the linked server name. That will great effort and not to mention that it might break the SP if something goes wrong.

Comment: I already know the risk that's why I'm looking for a better solution... it's tedious to scan SPs and modified the linked server name - again it's a legacy implementation of linked server...Is there's a better solution instead of manual way of doing it?

Comment: @Meow3301. I don't understand what you mean. My approach is keep the linked server name [ProductionServerName] in SP, but just change its definition to the TEST server, so that the SP will actually querying to the TEST server without any SP modification. Isn't that you want? Just like what Squirerel  said, but use [ProductionServerName] like a generic name.

Comment: But when you edit the linked server property the linked server is disable.. I'm not sure if i have an access to do that. Have you ever tried your suggestion? I mean you can edit the Linked server field?

Comment: Change your mind. If you cannot edit it, just delete it, and re-create it with the same name

Comment: I'm not sure on deleting the linked server. Also, it seems that the linked server name is actually the server path itself so recreating with the same name don't change a thing. I guess you haven't tried your suggestion and providing a logic-base answer. But i think we're on the same page where we can't find a better solution...Thanks anyway...

Comment: @Meow3301, I answer you because I have experience on it and of couse tried before. Check my answer below.

Comment: @Ivien, kindly explain the warning prompt before deleting the linked server and what are repercussions? I post this question because we already have that idea of delete and re-create but some developer says that using "Other data source" might not support instance server like "prodservername\i02,14333" and might interrupt other teams using this test server. That's why we are not sure how to proceed. So we are thinking of other measure aside from what you are suggesting...

Answer (score 0):

@Meow3301, seems You are not familar with sql server. Please check below screen cap:

[image]

What you need to do is delete the existing one from **Server Objects -> Linked Server** and re-create the Linked Server with YOUR [ProductionServerName] and change the **Data source** to your TEST server (no matter the server name or ip address), that's all!

Comment: Of course I'm familiar with sql server but I'm not familiar dealing with linked server. I want to try your suggestion yesterday but it gives a warning prompt and I'm not sure how to deal with the warning saying "Deleting a remote server deletes all remote logins defined for that server. Are you sure you want to delete this linked server and all remote logins defined for this server?". This test server is used by many teams and deleting the linked server may cause issues. You said you tried it before right, care of explaining that warning and what are repercussions?

Comment: @Meow3301, chekc https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9993e224-026d-44e0-8285-a19de8ea7a8b/what-happens-when-you-delete-a-linked-server?forum=sqlsecurity

Comment: We already checked that forum...My plan is to replicate the setup of linked server in my local sql server and see the effect of deleting linked server. I mean it's not that we don't understand that forum, is just that there is a big risk if thing went wrong in corporate server. Thanks for giving your thoughts...